# how to extract website from google map search

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

I need exact company information such as name, website url etc,after search by google map. everything is ok, but at last i can not locate the element website.it can open website after you click the image.[image: web site image]
but i can not find where the url element locate

anyone can help to locate the website url element? I use python selenium, only the last step, you can check the finished code as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps/@35.780287,104.1374349,4z')
sleep(8)
place=driver.find_element_by_class_name('tactile-searchbox-input')
place.send_keys('oil and gas solutions+UAE')
sleep(8)
submit=driver.find_element_by_id('searchbox-searchbutton')
submit.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the working code - Instead of `sleep` you should use `WebdriverWait`. Always use explicit waits, its a good practice.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in/maps')

SearchTextbox = driver.find_element_by_id("searchboxinput")
SearchTextbox.send_keys("cafe coffee day")
SearchTextbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

All_SearchResults = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-value="Website"]/button')))

for CCD in All_SearchResults:
    print(CCD.get_attribute("aria-label"))

print("end...")
```

Do let me know if this is what you are looking for. And if it is then please mark it as answer.

Comment: thanks for your response, however this way can not get url. only get just like this "visit Good Day Coffee Co.'s website'

Comment: do you see the comment,aria-label atrribute is not a url.woudl you mind check again where is the url？ because I checked several days ， i am stuck here